# loadingbar is not working with navbar <nav> in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-mobile

I need your help.
I am using loadingbar for my page like youtube, it works perfectly on page but when I use with navigation bar it is not working. this is my code for navigation, i don't know where is my problem, please help what solution can be. Thanks in advance.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="height:70px;width: 100%; position: fixed;top: 0;z-index: 999; box-shadow:  0 0 4px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6); padding-right: 10px;   ">
</nav>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: thanks for comment, i just edited . you can see now code.

Comment: I think you should post the full source. that would be great

Comment: Actually it is working behind the navigation bar

Comment: Hmm, I think the cause is `z-index`

Comment: the whole code is too large, and if i remove z-index: 999; then loadingbar appear perfectly, but my content which will be scrolled behind the navbar, it makes problem, content is displaying infront of navbar.

Comment: yeah, exactly, the problem is z-index. is there any solution that my content can be scrolled behind the navbar and also loadbar works perfectly?

Comment: As I post answer, please add z-index:1000 into loading bar

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add z-index to loading bar. `z-index: 1000`

Comment: if i remove z-index, its works but content problem occur.

Comment: don't remove z-index in navigation element, just add z-index into loading element